# Was the recent bust of 12 people in Florida the largest food stamp bust in history?

Tags: united-states, scam

The United States Department of Justice, in September 2017 sent out the following [press release.](https://www.justice.gov/usao-sdfl/pr/12-defendants-charged-federally-collectively-receiving-over-20-million-usda)

> **12 Defendants Charged Federally with Collectively Receiving Over $20 Million from USDA by Fraudulently Trading Food Stamps for Cash**
>
> Twelve retail store owners, operators, and clerks, have been charged in connection with schemes to illegally redeem food stamp benefits in exchange for cash.
>
> (...)
>
> The indictments allege that the retailers received more than $20 million in federal payments for transactions in which they did not provide any food, a fraud scheme commonly known as “food stamp trafficking.” Stores and vendors allegedly took illicit profits from the fraudulent transactions with food stamp recipients.  **This operation resulted in the largest combined financial fraud loss for a food stamp trafficking takedown in history.**

Is this true?

Comment: Shouldn't the title address what point is being questioned? And what's the relevance of their faith?

Comment: Also tapainfo seems EXTREMELY suspicious for a possible fake news site.  The about us page, in particular, isn't even filled out, but instead has the latin copypasta "Lorem Ipsum" used as placeholder text.

Comment: @jeffronicus I just used the headline on the article.

Comment: "Contact Us" is also empty as all hell, with an address located in Glasgow, a fake phone number, a fake email address

Comment: @DenisS  Yep, seems almost too perfect for a question here though

Comment: Hell, the whois info on the home page says that this website was created on Thursday.

Comment: "[W]hat was the next in line for a fraud loss involving Food Stamps?" is not asking about a notable claim.

Comment: @Laurel The notable claim is this the largest.  I might be begging the question, but it seems if providing some rank order would help qualify that.

Comment: For anyone having issues with the article referenced, just click on the DOJ link that KDog also provided. If you have as much issue with the DOJ release, tighten your foil hat.  From the DOJ press release - "This operation resulted in the largest combined financial fraud loss for a food stamp trafficking takedown in history." The DOJ claiming that seems notable.

Comment: I can agree that the question "Is this the largest food stamp bust in history?" Is legit.  What I can't agree with is the use of tapainfo.com as a website.  The website is trying to conflate Muslims with this case, which, in addition to being irrelevant, isn't even true if you read the actual indictment.  I'm going to rewrite the question without using tapainfo.com because using that site as the primary source will earn a close vote from me for lacking notability.

Comment: @DenisS  sure, go ahead

Comment: Another reason to not trust tapainfo : the DOJ release was from over a year ago.

Comment: @KDog done, although you may want to adjust the question more to your liking as I did a quick job on it.

Comment: @DenisS  It's fine.  People get too literal on these things and can't discern the substance.  This was substantively useful.  I used to be a reporter, and the vanity edits were always the worst.

Comment: @DenisS I think it's a great edit. Thank you for making the site better.

Comment: No problem fred :)

Comment: Here's a Breitbart link about the same operation: https://www.breitbart.com/politics/2017/10/02/12-floridians-charged-with-running-alleged-20-million-food-stamp-fraud-scheme/ The religion of the criminals is of course clearly irrelevant and Breitbart doesn't mention it.

Comment: @kdog If this is from the DOJ, why would you doubt it? They'd be pretty authoritative and exactly positioned to know. Perhaps we should have left the question alone and answered with the DOJ link.

Comment: @fredsbend Because they offered nothing relative to other busts that could put this into context.  And, also seriously, the DOJ?

Comment: @kdog Sorry, but in my circles the DOJ is not known for falsities and lies. FAA, FDA, and DOD are the target of criticism among my friends and family. Recently also the FTC and FCC.

Comment: The original question quoted two sources.  One was the DoJ, which was de-sensationalized and boring, and another source that was not notable.  The non-notable source was deleted and left with the DoJ.